# UIBarButtonItems spacing is huge on iOS 10 compared to iOS 11

Tags: ios, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, xcode9

So the app I'm working on has some social media icon buttons as UIBarButtonItems.

I have each of the icons in Assets as @1, @2, and @3 at 24x24, 48x48, 72x72.

When ran on an iPhone X at iOS 11:

[image: iOS 11 Nav Bar screenshot]

This looks ok. I'd actually prefer less spacing in between the icons, but I believe that might be out of the scope of this question.

The problem is when I run it on iPhone 5s iOS 10:

[image: iPhone 5s iOS 10]

Now I have those labels there to help aid in some code to manage clicking. Basically I check the label of the button pressed. If its FACEBOOK, then use the fb url, etc. But why are the labels showing up in iOS 10? Why are the buttons spaced so far apart?

I'm using Xcode 9.2

Comment: "why are the labels showing up" Because you are putting them there. This was always a terrible strategy for identifying the button pressed.

Comment: @matt fair enough. I guess setting the tag would be a better idea?

Comment: Almost anything would be a better idea. Don't hide values as _interface_.

Answer (score -1):

Please elaborate the question for clarity. However I'll try my best to answer. 
It looks like you have made custom view and the problem with spacing must be because of layout. Please check [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/) and see if that helps.